# Gtk time picker widget

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am looking for a GtkWidget to pick a time value. It does not have to be as sophisticated as [the carousel Android provides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejv5y.png), [two linked number input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A3kx.png) would suffice. Ideally, if the minute field rolls over 60 or 0, the hour field should change.

I found no such widget shipped with GTK (version 3.22) itself. There is only the far more complex GtkCalendar for dates.

Am I missing an easy way to implement such a class? Or is something like it available in a third-part-library?

Comment: There used to be a Widget for this in the (now long-deprecated) gnome library. It's not entirely simple, thanks to the necessity to implement both AM/PM and 24 hour clocks, and making this dependent on the local usage locale.

Answer (score 7):

There aren't any native GTK widgets for this, but the Gnome Date & Time settings uses two [GtkSpinButtons](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSpinButton.html) in vertical orientation:

[image: Gnome Date & Time settings]

Comment: There is not widget for time but there is a widget to pick date so that should remain same.

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this, keep in mind that chopping the date/time into a bunch of different fields may look pretty but makes efficient copy-paste impossible unless you implement some special trick for it. That may be fine for the dialog that let's you set system time, but can be very bad for a more general date/time input/output.